# Chef appbox with Error executing action `create` on resource 'user_account[deploy]'

Tags: deployment, chef-infra, vagrant, knife

I test the chef in vagrant of ubuntu 12.04. And I use the default vagrant account `vagrant` to run `knife solo bootstrap vagrant@192.168.33.10` and every time it shows the error below:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'user_account[deploy]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
user[deploy] (/home/vagrant/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/user/providers/account.rb line 94) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '6'
---- Begin output of ["useradd", "-c", "deployer", "-g", "deploy", "-s", "/bin/bash", "-u", "9001", "-d", "/home/deploy", "-m", "deploy"] ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: useradd: group 'deploy' does not exist
---- End output of ["useradd", "-c", "deployer", "-g", "deploy", "-s", "/bin/bash", "-u", "9001", "-d", "/home/deploy", "-m", "deploy"] ----
Ran ["useradd", "-c", "deployer", "-g", "deploy", "-s", "/bin/bash", "-u", "9001", "-d", "/home/deploy", "-m", "deploy"] returned 6
```

This disappointed me so much. Hope someone can help me.

And here is my node config file(/nodes/vagrant.json):

```
{
  "appbox": {
    "admin_keys":[  "ssh-rsa blabla" ],
    "deploy_keys":[  "ssh-rsa blabla" ]
  },
  "databox": {
    "db_root_password": "welcome!",
    "databases": {
      "mysql": [
        {
          "username": "get_real",
          "password": "get_real",
          "database_name": "get_real"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "github_deploys": {
    "deploy_user": "deploy",
    "github_api": {
      "username": "xxx",
      "email": "xxx@163.com",
      "password": "blabla"
    }
  },
  "rackbox": {
    "ruby": {
      "versions": ["2.0.0-p247"],
      "global_version": "2.0.0-p247"
    }
  },
  "run_list":[
    "databox::mysql",
    "nodejs",
    "rackbox",
    "github-deploys"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be helpful if you can provide code of your cookbook. However, the error message is quite clear.

```
---- Begin output of ["useradd", "-c", "deployer", "-g", "deploy", "-s", "/bin/bash", "-u", "9001", "-d", "/home/deploy", "-m", "deploy"] ----
```

From this line, we known chef tried to execute the following command to create a user namely `deploy` in `deploy` group.

```
useradd -c deployer -g deploy -s /bin/bash -u 9001 -d /home/deploy -m deploy
```

Then, the error message is:

```
STDERR: useradd: group 'deploy' does not exist
```

The solution should be simple: create a `deploy` group before creating this user. You can use the builtin [group](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_group.html) resource to do this.

Comment: Yeah, but I am using the `rackbox` and `databox` which should run with out any config. I update my question and include the node config file.

Comment: @aisensiy Adding the node attributes isn't going to change the fact that you need to create the missing 'deploy' group before trying to create the user. You need to look into the chef recipe code.